# shortcode not working

Tags: shortcode, plugins

I m working on content-product of woocommerce and doing shortcode in the template as `echo do_shortcode ('[product_attribute attribute="Grams"]');` where Grams are in my backend as attribute and it hasvalues, but nothing get printed out.Is it a wrong query or i need to do something else?

Comment: Did you add the shortcode using `add_shortcode()`?

Comment: no, i just did `do_shortcode()`, where should i be adding `add_shortcode`

Comment: If the `[product_attribute]` shortcode does not exist then you must create it. Take a look at [how to use/create shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: I don't know much about woocommerce specifically but you need to make sure that the shortcode is added to begin with. Can you look in the plugin and find where it is added? See the link in the comment above.

Comment: Apparently [`product_attribute`](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes#section-13) is a shortcode for WooCommerce. Where are you placing it in your template? I would assume it needs to be in the loop to grab the correct product ID.

Comment: @helgatheviking like i mention i am placing it under content-product page and between where i do it to be i.e
`do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
 </a>
      <div style="border:1px solid red;">
echo do_shortcode ('[product_attribute attribute="Grams"]');
</div>
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );`

Comment: @helgatheviking i tried doing echo do_shortcode( '[fblike]' )`and that worked, still the `[produce_attribute]` isn't

Comment: what about doing `echo do_shortcode( '[product_attribute]'` on its own?

Comment: @mantis no, that didn't help. it display nothing like before.

Comment: see below. Did that work?

Comment: "I would assume it needs to be in the loop to grab the correct product ID" -- I assume so too but as this is specific to WooCommerce, a third party plugin, the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the problem (from [product_attribute](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-13))

```
array(
 'per_page' => '12',
 'columns' => '4',
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order' => 'asc',
 'attribute' => 'asc',
 'filter' => 'asc'
)

[product_attribute attribute='color' filter='black']
```

Notice the attibute is in single quotes wheras yours is in double quotes:

```
do_shortcode ('[product_attribute attribute="Grams"]');
```

also you may need it to be in lowercase letters.

From [The codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes):

IMPORTANT TIP - Don't use camelCase or UPPER-CASE for your $atts attribute names
$atts values are lower-cased during shortcode_atts( array( 'attr_1' => 'attr_1 default', // ...etc ), $atts ) processing, so you might want to just use lower-case.

Comment: i tied that before posting here, but it didn't work. how can i find where is `woocommerce_single_product_summary`, maybe i can extract things that i want from it?

Comment: So you changed it to `do_shortcode ('[product_attribute attribute='grams']');`? because it specifically says not to use capital letters as attributes and you do need single quotes.

Comment: the code gives a highlight, i used double quotes as its quotes inside quotes.

Comment: Try inversing them using the double quotes on the outside. Also did you change grams to lowercase?

Comment: Also did you try something instead of attribute? Like `order='asc'`

Comment: no, i didn't. perhaps you have some dummy site and execute and see if it works

Comment: could it be because that what i want is value for each item, but in codex it says `[product_attribute attribute='color' filter='black']` but my example would exclude filter, because i have like items and every item has its own values in grams, can be the case?

Comment: I would think that based on the example you would need something along the line of [product_attribute attribute='grams' filter='100'] does this apply to your situation? There must be somewhere where you identify which attributes to include and their values.