# Shortcodes not working in category or tag description

Tags: categories, shortcode, taxonomy, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

when Yoast plugin is enabled shortcodes not working in category or tag description

I used [this](https://webgilde.com/en/shortcode-not-working-category-description/) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232411/how-get-a-shortcode-working-in-category-description) article and add these codes to the function but nothing change
please help me.

```
add_filter( ‘term_description’, ‘do_shortcode’ );
add_filter( ‘category_description’, ‘do_shortcode’ );
add_filter( ‘post_tag_description’, ‘do_shortcode’ );


function my_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/html/htmlcontent.php');
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode("shortcode","my_shortcode");
```

**Update:** When I use the below code everything fine. I don't know whats the problem

```
function my_shortcode() {
    $url = get_template_directory() . '/html/my_shortcode.php';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shortcode not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123993/shortcode-not-working)

Comment: @Farukrıza no. I think my shortcode function has a problem

Comment: You don't actually use the `‘` in your code, do you? But even if you don't, you should change it to `'` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You entered the quotation marks wrong, I fixed it, maybe it will help:

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'category_description', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'post_tag_description', 'do_shortcode' );

function my_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/html/htmlcontent.php');
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode("shortcode","my_shortcode");
```